# How to capture an image using selenium pythons script

Tags: python, selenium-rc

I want to test the image displayed in my web application. please anyone provide me the solution. 
I have used sel.capture_entire_page_screenshot("C:\Users\test\Desktop\privacy.png", "")
it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

One problem with that is that the backslashes aren't escaped, so `\t`
becomes a tab character. Try this (the `r` makes it a "raw string" where
backslashes have no special meaning):

```
sel.capture_entire_page_screenshot(r"C:\Users\test\Desktop\privacy.png", "")
```